# Renci SSH.Net SFTP Intermittent connection issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, sftp, ssh.net

I am having issues uploading files from an ASP.NET server to our CDN (Akamai) using Renci SSH SFTP. Before the launch that started the issues we had been using FTP to upload media, and anything over ~50MB would start to have 502 Bad Gateway issues. Since we wanted to update to SFTP for security anyways, we swapped out our FTP code for SFTP to see if the problem persisted. In our dev and QA environments this seemed tp fix that issue, but admittedly with much lower traffic than our prod server. Once in production, we had around 3k uploads, and of those uploads about 30% of them failed with the following error, originating in Renci SSH.Net

```
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

The interesting thing is this only happens when the code is being executed by ASP.NET. I made a console application that calls the Services.dll, provides the path to the media files, and provides a decent sized list of test media ranging is size from 800 KB to 187 MB. When running on the server as a console application not a single error was thrown. Therefore I think the issue is somewhere in ASP.NET, IIS, or some server setting I am not aware of.

Our firewall is set up to allow communication to Akamai through port 22 for ssh, which I had my team verify for each of the load balanced servers. Since the console application is running fine I don't think this is the issue. But it is worth mentioning that I looked

The admin panel that is called to upload media items is on an aspx page which I'll call "upload.aspx" for now. In the web config we extended the execution timeout for the upload.aspx to this:

```
<location path="path/to/upload.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="204800" executionTimeout="2700" />
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Here is the code making the connection

```
using(var client = new SftpClient(GetConnectionInfo()))
{
    client.ConnectionInfo.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

    //This is the line that is hit before the error.
    //It attempts to connect for about 20 seconds and throws an error.
    //Happens with or without ConnectionInfo.Timeout being set.
    client.Connect();

    //perform logic to upload file, then disconnect
    client.Disconnect();
}
```

One last note, the length of time to upload any file is significantly slower than using FTP. I've heard of this happening for other companies and am not surprised by this, but it may help in troubleshooting the issue.

Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the TCP setting Max SYN Retransmissions of the operating system. The default is 21 for windows. You can only lower the timeout with client.ConnectionInfo.Timeout.

More info here: https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/issues/183#issuecomment-299283600